# Backbone infinite scrolling on window

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, infinite-scroll

I tried to change things around this tutorial and faced problem:

http://backbonetutorials.com/infinite-scrolling/

Basically the tutorial is about scroll within a `div`. I already have a `div` but I scroll on the `window`. I don't want to set the `window` with `overflow:scroll` because it will add ugly horizontal scroller.

I created a new view with `el: $('body')` and add below in `initialize`:

```
  _.bindAll(this, 'checkScroll');
  $(window).scroll(this.checkScroll);
```

However, I don't think the below variables act right:

```
this.el.scrollTop + this.el.clientHeight + triggerPoint > this.el.scrollHeight
```

Any idea how to fix this for the `window` or `body` object?

Comment: hmm I think I figured it out using `$(document).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - triggerPoint`

Answer (score 0):

It is:

```
$(document).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - triggerPoint
```